# How to prove properties of non-linear operators involved in LEB128 algorithm in Dafny?

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I'm trying to prove that encoding/decoding a (signed) LEB128 algorithm is lossless.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128

What's got me stuck is the "Sign Extension" operation for the negative numbers.
Since the integers in Dafny is unbounded, I have to use stuff like `%` and `/` to simulate the sign extension, which I guess stuck the solver.
The property I tried to prove is `SLebLosslessNeg`, its positive counterpart can be derived automatically by Dafny.

Here is my code:

```
type LEB128 = seq<bv8>

function Abs(n: int) : int
{
  if (n < 0) then -n else n
}

function SEncode(N: int) : (S: LEB128)
  decreases Abs(N)
  ensures |S| > 0
  ensures S[|S|-1] < 0x80
  ensures N < 0 <==> S[|S|-1] % 128 >= 64
  ensures N >= 0 <==> S[|S|-1] % 128 < 64
{
  var c := (N % 128) as bv8;
  var r := N / 128;
  if (r == 0 && c < 64) || (r == -1 && c >= 64) then
    [c]
  else
    [c + 0x80] + SEncode(r)
}

function SDecode(S: LEB128) : (N: int)
  requires |S| > 0
  requires S[|S|-1] < 0x80
{
  if S[|S|-1] < 0x40 then
    SDecodePos(S)
  else
    SDecodeNeg(S, 1)
}

function SDecodePos(S: LEB128) : (N: int)
  requires |S| > 0
  requires S[|S|-1] < 0x80
  ensures N >= 0
{
  if |S| == 1 then
    S[0] as int
  else
    (S[0] - 0x80) as int + 128 * SDecodePos(S[1..])
}

function SDecodeNeg(S: LEB128, carry: bv8) : (N: int)
  requires |S| > 0
  requires S[|S|-1] < 0x80
  ensures N <= 0
{
  var c := if |S| == 1 then S[0] else S[0] - 0x80;
  if |S| == 1 then
    var temp := ((!c - 0x80) + carry) as int;
    -temp
  else
    var temp := ((!c - 0x80) + carry) as int;
    -temp + 128 * SDecodeNeg(S[1..], (c / 128) as bv8)
}

lemma SLebLosslessPos(n: int)
  requires n >= 0
  ensures SDecode(SEncode(n)) == n
{}

lemma SLebLosslessNeg(s: LEB128, n: int)
  requires |s| > 0
  requires n < 0
  requires s == SEncode(n)
  ensures SDecode(s) == n
{}


method Main() {
  var i := -100000;
  while i < 100000 {
    var s := SEncode(i);
    var n := SDecode(s);
    print s, " ",  n, " ", i == n, " ", i, "\n";
    i := i + 1;
  }
```

<del>I think the `pow` is causing the issue here as Dafny couldn't figure out how to connect it to the 2's complement, but I don't know how to tell Dafny such things.
I have a rather vague idea of bounding each `n` using `0 <= n < 2^p` and showing Dafny such a thing holds, but it's just an idea, and I don't know how to approach it...</del>

Also, I tested my algorithm with input in [-100000, 100000], and the results are correct.

**EDIT:**
Updated to include functions. Thanks, @Hath995.

I tried to approach this problem in a more step-wise way.

In short, I have updated the code to do the complement as the `SDecode` proceeds. But it still does not work. I think it's that Dafny could not figure out the link between the complement and the encoding process.

In the encoding, there is no *explicit* complement occurs, Dafny does this automatically due to the feature of Euclidean division, but it fails to do so when the process is reversed.

**EDIT**
Removed confusing assumption.

Comment: You should include your definition of pow(), abs(), and LEB128 and byte.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? As is your code seems to verify and the main function tests all seem to return true. If you are trying to add a postcondition which is not verifying or prove a lemma please add them to your example. Is it SLebLosslessNeg that you need proved?

Comment: To prove SLebLosslessNeg you will likely need to break it down by cases based on |s| like you do in SDecodeNeg and use calc to assert what happens to the values, and then call SLebLosslessNeg as needed to complete the induction.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.
I am still new to Dafny. I tried to breakdown based on |s|, but I didn't try the `calc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hath995, I have come up with a solution.

The key to the proof is two parts.

1. There are TWO cases of SDecode's result. `carry == 0` and `carry == 1`. Both are needed to be included in the base case where `|s| == 1`.
2. Need to show the equivalence between `X % 128 - 128` and `(!X & 0x7f) + 1`

The proof is as follows.

```
  lemma SLebLosslessNeg(s: LEB128, n: int)
    requires |s| > 0
    requires n < 0
    requires s == SEncode(n)
    ensures SDecode(s) == n
  {
    //assume {:axiom} SDecode(SEncode(n)) == n;
    if |s| == 1 {
      assert SDecode(s) == n;
      assert SDecodeNeg(s, 0) == n + 1; // base case 1: carry == 0
      assert SDecodeNeg(s, 1) == n;     // base case 2: carry == 1
    } else {
      calc {
        SDecode(s);
        -(((!(s[0] - 0x80) - 0x80) + 1) as int) + 128 * SDecodeNeg(s[1..], 0);
        -(((!((n % 128) as bv8) - 0x80) + 1) as int) + 128 * SDecodeNeg(s[1..], 0);
        (n % 128) - 128 + 128 * SDecodeNeg(s[1..], 0);
        { SLebLosslessNeg(s[1..], n / 128); }
        (n % 128) - 128 + 128 * (n / 128 + 1);
      }
    }
  }
```